# Replace CSS url()'s?

Tags: php, css, regex, url

Imagine I have a string, `$my_css_string`, and we know it contains CSS styling.

Now imagine I have a function `string url_replace(string $url)` that returns a modified URL that I want to replace every `url()` with in `$my_css_string`.

So, for simplicity's sake, let's say `url_replace()` ALWAYS returns the string `"xxxx"`.

How can you go through `$my_css_string`, find each `url()` in the string, and replace that URL with what you get from `url_replace()`?

---

So, if you had this CSS as `$my_css_string`:

```
@import url('http://example.com/css/animals.css');
.dog {
    background:url("/images/dog.png");
    border:1px solid rgb(0,0,128);
}
.cat {
    background:url(http://example.com/images/cat.gif);
}
```

If you ran the code, `$my_css_string` would become:

```
@import url('xxxx');
.dog {
    background:url( "xxxx" );
    border:1px solid rgb(0,0,128);
}
.cat {
    background:url(xxxx);
}
```

Notice how it needs to handle multiple ways of defining URLs.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$my_new_css_string = preg_replace_callback(
                        '/background-image:\s*url\(\s*([\'"]*)(?P<file>[^\1]+)\1\s*\)/i',
                        'url_replace',
                        $my_css_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php. You should be able to search for 'url(.*)' and then implement custom logic in the call back to handle the various replacement scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not that picky you could use the following expression to match `url()`s:

```
/\b url\( \s*+ \K  (?| (") ( (?>[^"\\]++|\\.)*+ ) " | (') ( (?>[^'\\]++|\\.)*+ ) ' | () ([\S)]*+) )  ( \s*+ \) )/ix
```

This expression will handle escapes correctly, but could also match in comments and strings, which may not be desired.

And then you can use it with `preg_replace_callback` or just with `/e`, eg:

```
preg_replace('/\b url\( \s*+ \K  (?| (") ( (?>[^"\\\\]++|\\\\.)*+ ) " | (\') ( (?>[^\'\\\\]++|\\\\.)*+ ) \' | () ([\S)]*+) )  ( \s*+ \) )/ixe', '"$1" . url_replace("$2") . "$1$3"', $css);
```